# Gnome shell extensions cannot be enabled, stay INITIALIZED

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

From one day to the next on my Ubuntu 22.04 amd64 all the shell extensions from the system tray went missing and seem to be inactive.

I already tried many problem solving attempts from this site and the rest of the Inet, so I believe my situation is rather special. Sorry in advance if I'm actually still missing something.

The situation:

- I checked "Extension Manager" and that the "big switch" on the top is on, toggled it multiple times. I also checked the respective dconf setting that extensions are not generally disabled.
- Of course I tried enabling via "Extension Manager". The switch goes on but nothing happens. Restarting EM will show the switch off again.
- On "gnome-extensions list -d" only 4 preinstalled extensions show as status "ENABLED". All others are "INITIALIZED"

  - One of the enabled ones is the desktop icons (ding), which apparently seems to work
- The "INITIALIZED" extensions stay in that status if I do "gnome-extensions enable/disable ..."
- I tried to

  - Purge an reinstall gnome-shell-extensions
  - Clear ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/
  - Install "user themes" extension

An example of the extensions list, featuring the working "ding" extension and the suddenly non-working "espresso" extension:

```
oliver@kempen:~/.config/dconf> gnome-extensions list -d

...

ding@rastersoft.com
  Name: Desktop Icons NG (DING)
  Description: Adds icons to the desktop. Fork of the original Desktop Icons extension, with several enhancements .
  Path: /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com
  URL: https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng
  State: ENABLED

...

espresso@coadmunkee.github.com
  Name: Espresso
  Description: Espresso disables the usual auto suspend and screensaver functionality and optionally Night Light with options to show an Espresso icon in the top panel, to enable Espresso when a fullscreen application is running, to restore state across reboots, to provide notifications, to enable Espresso when specific applications are running, or to pause Night Light when Espresso is enabled or only when specific applications are running. Espresso also provides some support for docking stations including options to enable Espresso when charging and/or when docked to external monitors and to allow temporarily overriding the docking support without affecting the stored state.

Espresso is a fork of the Caffeine extension.

Please leave feedback or report issues through the Extension Homepage
  Path: /home/oliver/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/espresso@coadmunkee.github.com
  URL: https://github.com/coadmunkee/gnome-shell-extension-espresso
  Version: 8
  State: INITIALIZED
```

Thanks for any insights!